# How do I write a regular expression to check for a url or a email address?

Tags: regex, user-input

Does anyone know a regular expression that checks for a valid url or an email address. I need the user to enter either a contact page url or email address. Here is the regex I have so far:

```
^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$
```

Comment: email address and urls can get very complex. It is very difficult to cover all the bases. There are domains that can end in co.uk and even museum! Probably searching google would be your best bet.I've seen regexes for emails that can make you dizzy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a google search for "Regular expression for URL" and "Regular Expression for email address". You will find lots of results.

Answer (score -2):

for email validation through preg_match

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/',$email)
```

may be this will help.

Comment: will u pls tell me the right format @bzlm, i'm also new in php. thankyou.